# How to get partially selected parent id in jstree

Tags: javascript, treeview, jstree

I am using "jstree" for treeview  (Parent-Child) structure uisng checkboxes and returning id for each selected item. But here I am getting only children's Id and not getting selected parent Id. Kindly help me to get it too.

click [`enter code here` http://jsfiddle.net/2kwkh2uL/5807/ ]to find the code.

Comment: Please don't do enter `code here to` to get around not having code with your fiddle. Include your code in your question.

Comment: I checked your plunker, I feel it's returning ids. Correct me where I am wrong

Comment: it's returning only selected child id but i want parent's id too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each object carries a key called `parent`, this contains the `id`. The answer below:

```js
$('#container').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : [
            { "text" : "P1", "children" : [
                { "text" : "O11" },
                { "text" : "O12" },
                { "text" : "O13"}     
            ]
            },
             { "text" : "P2", "children" : [
                { "text" : "O21" },
                { "text" : "O22" },
                { "text" : "O23"}     
            ]
            },
        ]
    },
    "plugins" : ["checkbox"]
});
$('#submitdiv').show();
  $('#submit').click(function(){
   var selectedElmsIds = [];
   var selectedElms = $('#container').jstree("get_selected", true);
   $.each(selectedElms, function() {
       selectedElmsIds.push(
          {
            id: this.id,
            parent: this.parent
          }
         );
       console.log('Id node: '+this.id);
       console.log('Id parent: '+this.parent);
   });
   console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedElmsIds));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.3/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.3/themes/default/style.min.css">

<div id="container"></div>
  <div id="submitdiv" style="display:none;position:absolute">
  <button id="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

**PS:** I apologize for my bad English, I speak Spanish and I'm using google translator.

Comment: @parul not problem